# UnitTest - tested method always return empty map

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am writing Unit Test for simple method, that should return map with items,
but every time maps returns 0 items.

Test is in Kotlin

```
@Test
fun `convertToMap`() {
  val items = listOf(Item(ID, false))
  val map = viewModel.convertToMap(items)
  assertThat(map[ID]).isFalse()
}
```

This test is failing as there is no item in map.

Code is in Java

```
public Map<String, Boolean> convertToMap(List<Item> items) {
  Map<String, Boolean> itemsMap = new ArrayMap<>();
  for (Item item: items) {
    itemsMap.put(item.getId(), item.isEnabled());
  }
  return itemsMap;
}
```

`List<Item> items` contains `item`, it is not `null`, `getId()` returns value, same as `isEnabled()`,

I have debugged the method each put does not increase map size. (items are't added to map)

dependencies added for tests:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockito_core}"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:${mockito_kotlin_inline}"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectric}"
testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:${google_truth}"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:${kotlin_version}"
```

edit: just to make clear, the `convertToMap()` works when run in standard environment.

Comment: which package or library does `ArrayMap` belong to?

Comment: @Roland,

wow, you are right. 
I was using import android.util.ArrayMap;
switched to import android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap;
and it worked. 
Could you elaborate why is that?

Comment: Just to make your example a little more of a [mcve], I wonder if you could change your test to assert the size of the map? Just to completely clarify your statement that "each put does not increase map size"?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave yes I have wrongly rewritten the code (wrong flag). 

Regarding size, I have also tests for that, but I new that I should receive object in the end.

Comment: I'm confused; in your question you say that the items are not being added to the map, but in the comment above you say that you have tests that assert the size of the map. If those tests pass, then your statement in the question must be incorrect, no? If those tests don't pass, then surely fixing those should be your first aim?

Comment: @Nimdokai no, I can't... I can't even believe that this is the solution, but I am not an Android expert, so I can't even tell, what's the difference between the two... could it be related with some configured Android SDK level?

Comment: @ DaveyDaveDave sorry for confusing you, I meant that I have method that checks that size is 0 which is passing, all others are failing, I knew the reason is inside what I have described above.

Comment: @Roland I can't also, but it truly works. thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change from

```
import android.util.ArrayMap;
```

to:

```
android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap;
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution as an answer. Please also mark it as correct.